# How to write unit tests for a directive that checks to see if 2 passwords match?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing an app with AngularJS 1.5 and I have a form that I want to validate.

The form has 2 fields: password and confirm password.

I want these validation conditions: missing password, missing confirmation password, and passwords must match.

I wrote a custom directive to handle the case of the passwords matching.

I want to write a unit test to check for various inputs before I give it to QA.

How can I write a test for this?

```
/* confirmPassword.directive.js */

(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('softworksSelfService')
        .directive('confirmPwd', confirmPasswordInput);

    function confirmPasswordInput() {

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            scope: {
                otherModelValue: '=confirmPwd'
            },
            require: 'ngModel'
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, elements, attributes, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$validators.match = function (modelValue) {
                return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
            };

            scope.$watch('otherModelValue', function () {
                ngModel.$validate();
            });

        }

    }

})();


            <input
                id="confirmPassword"
                type="password"
                name="confirmPassword"
                ng-model="data.confirmPassword"
                placeholder="confirm password"
                confirm-pwd="data.password"
                required>
```